# Importing data from Access to Excel using Access VBA

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I'd like to ask you for the help with the Access VBA code, that would import all the data from 1 specified query table from the Access database (currently open database) to MS Excel (the file, that could be selected by the user).

I'm currently having this piece of code, but I'm getting the error message saying:

> "Run-time error '-2147023170 (800706be)':
>
> Automation error The remote procedure call failed."

Would any of you know how to fix the connection?

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Database

    Public Sub CopyRstToExcel_test()
    'On Error GoTo CopyRstToExcel_Err

        Dim sPath As String
        Dim fd As FileDialog
        Dim oExcel As Object
        Dim oExcelWrkBk As Object
        Dim oExcelWrSht As Object

        Dim dbs 'Added
        Dim qdfName As String
        Dim fRecords As Boolean

        Dim rst As dao.Recordset

        Dim iCols As Integer

        '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ' Select the file and identify the path leading to the file
        '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        'Define database you want to work with
        Set dbs = CurrentDb

        'Select the Excel file you want to work with
        Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

        'Define the path
        If fd.Show = -1 Then
            sPath = fd.SelectedItems(1)
        End If

        MsgBox sPath

        '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ' Defining names of variables
        '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        'Defining variables (queries/tables)
        qdfName = "Query_1"

        '------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        'Copying the data from Access into the new Excel
        '------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(qdfName, dbOpenSnapshot)

        fRecords = False
        If rst.EOF = False Then
            fRecords = True

            Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
            Set oExcelWrkBk = GetObject(sPath)

            oExcel.Visible = True
            oExcel.ScreenUpdating = False

            Set oExcelWrSht = oExcelWrkBk.Sheets(1)

            For iCols = 0 To rst.Fields.Count - 1
                oExcelWrSht.Cells(9, iCols + 2).Value = rst.Fields(iCols).Name
            Next

            oExcelWrSht.Range(oExcelWrSht.Cells(9, 2), _
                oExcelWrSht.Cells(9, rst.Fields.Count)).Font.Bold = True

            oExcelWrSht.Range("B10").CopyFromRecordset rst

            oExcelWrSht.Range(oExcelWrSht.Cells(9, 2), _
                oExcelWrSht.Cells(rst.RecordCount + 9, rst.Fields.Count)).Columns.AutoFit

            oExcelWrSht.Range("A1").Select

        End If


    '------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    CopyRstToExcel_Done:
        On Error Resume Next
        If fRecords = True Then
            oExcel.Visible = True
            oExcel.ScreenUpdating = True
        End If
        Set oExcelWrSht = Nothing
        Set oExcelWrkBk = Nothing
        Set oExcel = Nothing
        Set rst = Nothing

    ''Error message:
    'CopyRstToExcel_Err:
    '    MsgBox Err & ": " & Error, vbExclamation
    '    Resume CopyRstToExcel_Done
    '    Resume
    '------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    End Sub
```

In this step, I only want to copy the data in the first sheet, but later on I would also like to specify the name of the sheet and I've got already prepared templates I want to copy the data over.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please specify where you get this error (which line)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace

```
Set oExcelWrkBk = GetObject(sPath)
```

by

```
Set oExcelWrkBk = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(sPath)
```

Also I'd recommend to replace

```
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(qdfName, dbOpenSnapshot)
```

by

```
Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset(qdfName, dbOpenSnapshot)
```

Open specified worksheet:

```
Set oExcelWrSht = oExcelWrkBk.Sheets("MyWorksheetName")
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much! These were exactly the adjustments I needed.